API call shows no content with function but works without a function. React/nextJS
Why when I use the getData() it shows it as empty, but works when I fetch without it?
// "use client";

export default async function Home() {
  async function getData() {
    const res = await fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts");
    return await res.json();
  }

  const res = await fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts");
  const data = await res.json();

  return (
    <>
      Why this shows an empty data {} : {JSON.stringify(getData(), null, 2)}
      And this not: {JSON.stringify(data, null, 2)}
    </>
  );
}


Using NextJS with app folders

Does this answer your question? Why is my asynchronous function returning Promise {  } instead of a value?

@Phil It is the right direction. But how to I fix it? Do I need another page on NextJS is there a simple way without useEffect?

I'm not sure what's unclear. getData() is an async function. It implicitly returns a promise. Attempting to stringify a promise won't show anything. If you want the data, you need to await the promise... JSON.stringify(await getData(), null, 2)

@Phill this is so much clear now!! thanks for the save!

@AlexeyTseitlin you defined a server component where you can't use useEffect. Either await the promise, or convert the component to a client component and use useEffect.

Server component
You should await the promise: const data = await getData()
export default async function Home() {
  async function getData() {
    const res = await fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts");
    return res.json();
  }
  const data = await getData();
  return (
    <>
      {JSON.stringify(data, null, 2)}
    </>
  );
}

Client component
"use client"

export default function Home() {
  async function getData() {
    const res = await fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts");
    return res.json();
  }
  const [data, setData] = React.useState();
  React.useEffect(() => {
    getData().then(setData).catch(console.error);
  }, []);
  return (
    <>
      {JSON.stringify(data, null, 2)}
    </>
  );
}


Why people thumbs down this solution? it works....

If it does, mark it as solved :) thanks!

what is "fetchData" in your code? if you meant "getData" then "getData.then()" is not working.....

I updated the answer. It is getData().then() rather than getData.then()
